# SQL failing in one page on some machines

Tags: php, sql

Edit: Forgot to mention none of the SQL works at all when it fails.

I seriously need help figuring this out. It has been about a month since the issue has arrived. I have rewrote the page a couple times and have tried removing some unneeded items in case it was a speed issue (had sidebar that auto scrolled and loaded in two social media widgets which was kinda slow on bad internet) and so far nothing. I really do not know why this happens at all.

Here is the kicker. It only happens to random people. Never breaks for me but breaks nearly every time for a customer on certain pc's. Another issue that person is running into is the cart cookie won't clear for that person either(just them).

I am Using Auth.net's DPM method which takes them offsite momentarily then to my Order_receipt page(the one in question). When arriving at that page you are given 2 $_GET properties example (order_receipt.php?response_code=1&transaction_id=136434353) which is coming in properly even when it fails.

Customer that has issue is using win 10, and has tried it with both chrome and edge running kaspersky antivirus (no issues on my end from either browser)

I'm going to include all code loaded and included in that page below, starting with the order_receipt itself.

** = redacted info

Order_receipt.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'system/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
include 'includes/headerpartial.php';

?>

<div id="maincontent" class="col-md-12">

<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', -1); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

ini_set('log_errors', 1);

ini_set('error_log', 'system/error_logs.log');

$error_code = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);




if ($_GET['response_code'] == 1)
{



  $trans_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

  if (isset($cart_id)){


  $db->query("UPDATE transactions SET charge_id = '$trans_id' WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'");




  $tsql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id' ");
  $tran = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tsql);




?>
<h1 id="reciept">Thank you for your support!</h1><hr>
<p id="reciept">
 On behalf of ** <?=$tran['full_name']?> we thank you for your purchase and hope you enjoy it!
</p>

<p id="reciept">
  You have selected <b>"<?=$tran['pickup-location']?>"</b> as your pickup point.
</p>

<table id="nav-button" class="table table-bordered table-auto">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction ID : <?=$tran['charge_id']?></td>
      </tr>
<?php
$a = 1;
$it = 1;
$string = $tran['items'];
$itemar = explode(',', $string);
$num = 1;

$istr = $tran['inventory'];
$stri = explode(',', $istr);


if ($tran['status'] != "Complete") {


foreach (array_slice($stri, $num) as $inve ){


  $exploded = explode('.', $inve);

  $itname = $exploded['0'];
  $itquan = $exploded['1'];


  $db->query("UPDATE products SET `quantity` = `quantity` - '$itquan' WHERE title = '$itname'");
$db->query("UPDATE products SET `Sold` = `Sold` + '$itquan' WHERE title = '$itname'");

    $it++;
   }
   $compl = "Complete";
  $db->query("UPDATE transactions SET `status` = '$compl' WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'");
}


foreach (array_slice($itemar, $num) as $itemr ){



  ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?=$itemr?></td>
      </tr>


    <?php

    $a++;
   } ?>

   <tr>
     <td>
       Total: <?=money($tran['grand_total']);?>
     </td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>




<?php
  $domain = '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);


}else{echo "Cart Id not Set";}



}else
{
echo "Sorry, an error occurred: ".htmlentities($_GET['response_reason_text']);
}?>

</div>


<?php

include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Init.php:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("**","**","**","**");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo 'Database connection failed with following errors: '. mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';

$cart_id = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){
  $cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['LHUser'])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['LHUser'];
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
  $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  $fn = explode(' ', $user_data['full_name']);
  $user_data['first'] = $fn[0];
  $user_data['last'] = $fn[1];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['success_flash'])) {
  echo '<div class="bg-success"><p class="text-success text-center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';
  unset($_SESSION['success_flash']);
}


if (isset($_SESSION['error_flash'])) {
  echo '<div class="bg-danger"><p class="text-danger text-center">'.$_SESSION['error_flash'].'</p></div>';
  unset($_SESSION['error_flash']);
}



 ?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
define('CART_COOKIE','Sd4CqdgRt6J3gd3F7');
define('CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE', time() + (86400 * 30));

 ?>
```

helpers.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
function display_errors($errors){
  $display = '<ul class="bg-danger">';
  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    $display .= '<li class="text-danger">'.$error.'</li>';
  }
  $display .= '</ul>';
  return $display;
}

function sanitize($dirty){
  return htmlentities($dirty,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");

}

function money($number){
  return '$'.number_format($number,2);
}

function login($user_id){
  $_SESSION['LHUser'] = $user_id;
  global $db;
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $db->query("UPDATE users SET last_login = '$date' WHERE id = '$user_id'");
  $_SESSION['success_flash'] = 'You are now logged in!';
  header('Location: index.php');
}

function is_logged_in(){
  if (isset($_SESSION['LHUser']) && $_SESSION['LHUser'] > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


function login_error_redirect($url = 'login.php'){
  $_SESSION['error_flash'] = 'You must be logged in to access that page';
  header('Location:'.$url);
}

function permission_error_redirect($url = 'login.php'){
  $_SESSION['error_flash'] = 'You don\'t have permission to access that page';
  header('Location:'.$url);
}


function has_permission($permission = 'admin'){
  global $user_data;
  $permissions = explode(',', $user_data['permissions']);
  if (in_array($permission,$permissions,true)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


function get_category($child_id){
  global $db;
  $id = sanitize($child_id);
  $sql = "SELECT p.id AS 'pid', p.category AS 'parent', c.id AS 'cid', c.category AS 'child'
          FROM categories c
          INNER JOIN categories p
          ON c.parent = p.id
          WHERE c.id = '$id'";
  $query = $db->query($sql);
  $category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  return $category;

}
```

head.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LettuceHeads</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="../images/header/logoicon.png">
  <meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script SRC="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

navigation.php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM navigation ORDER BY `navigation`.`sort` ASC";
$pquery = $db->query($sql);
 ?>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div id="navtext" class="containter">
   <a id="navborder" href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">**</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pquery)) : ?>
    <li id="navborder"><a href="<?=$parent['url'];?>"><?=$parent['name'];?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </li>

  </ul>
  <ul  id="navright" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

    <li id="navborder2"><a href="cart.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> My Cart</a></li>
  <?php  if(has_permission('admin')): ?>
      <li id="navborder"><a href="admin/index.php">Staff</a></li>
  <?php endif; ?>
</ul>

 </div>
</nav>
```

headerpartial.php:

```
<div id="partialHeaderWrapper">
  <div id="partialbackitem"></div>
  <div id="partiallogotext"></div>
  <div id="partialfore-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
```

footer.php:

Comment: What fails?  What is the error?  Logs?  With the little info first thing that comes to mind is cookie and URI related.  eg. domain.com to www.domain.com.

Comment: I have checked the cookies, they are there and functioning. And what fails is none of the SQL on the Order_receipt.php page will run for them. I get no real errors. That is part of the issue. Literally the only thing that happens is the sql doesn't run which means the database isn't updated.

Comment: In a project I used to work on, we found that certain browsers would append extra characters to certain requests.  No idea if this is possible in your case but is there any consistency in browser/version when the SQL fails?  Is there something unique about the specific computers that always fail? Different firewall rules? Browser updates? Browser add-ons?

Comment: I think you need more logging code on Order_reciept.php.  If no error then assume conditions not met for say `if ($_GET['response_code'] == 1)` in which case log everything in your `else` block and figure out why down is up.  The connection between your server side code and the client is limited... it's not a browser issue or client plugin issue in the sense a JavaScript bug could be, it is as finite as what is passed in HTTP request.

Comment: @Kalmino I will see. so far all I know they both have is kaspersky. I will let you know what they say.

Comment: @ficuscr Would you mine explaining this a bit more I don't quite get what you are saying. (outside more error logging.)